# Creating a feature however manifest does not contain GUID ID

Tags: feature-activation, web-template, guid

Currently I am creating four custom features within a visual studio sharepoint 2010 project. Within the manifest there is no ID generated once the feature has been created for two of the features. All four features are scoped at Site level.

I am trying to find the ID as I would like to add this to a web template. Does anyone know why the ID is not being generated. I currently have four features two contain an ID and the other two do not.

Comment: And it is not visible in the Properties panel?

Comment: They are available in the properties panel. Should they not also be visible in the manifest.xml? If they are not does it not matter?

Comment: Not sure when and if they are written to the manifest.xml, could very well be on build